# how do i convert a 8-bit binary number into 6-bit?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x;

    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

    printf("type a integer.");
    scanf("%d", &x);

    printf("%d : ", x);

    printf("%d", x & 0x80 ? 1 : 0); x <<= 1;
    printf("%d", x & 0x80 ? 1 : 0); x <<= 1;
    printf("%d", x & 0x80 ? 1 : 0); x <<= 1; 
    printf("%d", x & 0x80 ? 1 : 0); x <<= 1;
    printf("%d", x & 0x80 ? 1 : 0); x <<= 1;
    printf("%d", x & 0x80 ? 1 : 0); x <<= 1;
    printf("%d", x & 0x80 ? 1 : 0); x <<= 1;
    printf("%d", x & 0x80 ? 1 : 0);

    return 0;
}
```

This is a code that can convert integer into a 8 bit binary number and I'm trying to make it print 6 bit binary number but I fail...

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you want the output to look like?

Comment: With a specific input, what is the expected and actual output?

Comment: you're shifting 6 times but masking the 8th bit. That doesn't work, of course.

Comment: Also note that you're not really *converting* anything, you're just printing *seven* bits of the contents of `x` (but not the least significant bit).

Comment: sorry! I mean I wanted to scan integer and print as a 6 bit binary number

Answer (score 2):

In each step the code above make a logical and operation between x and 0x80. In binary 0x80 is 10000000. So in each operation we are getting if the current most significant bit of x is 1 or 0. In each iteration x is right shifted to 1 bit. So after all the operations. we get the initial integer in 8 bit binary. To get the value in 6 bit, you need to make a logical and operation between x and 0x20(Which is in binary 100000).

Comment: I was an idiot!!!!! thanks it helped a lot.....I'm such a newb and these things gets me so confused

Answer (score 0):

Your code is masking the 8th bit of your number, which introduces a shift, and yields incorrect result.

I would just generate a mask within a loop using shifting:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x,i;

    printf("type an integer.");
    scanf("%d", &x);

    for (i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
       printf("%d", (x & (1<<(5-i))) != 0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

or adapting your attempt within a loop & correct mask position (changes `x`), and using the idiomatic integer to bool double negation trick:

```
for (i=0;i<6;i++)
{
   printf("%d", !!(x & 0x20));
   x <<= 1;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! I'm not good with a loop yet but this will help a lot i think.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 yes, it's better.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to shift the mask than to modify the original value - that is aan unnecessarily *destrictove* algorithm, and since that is a known value you can simply use constants:

```
printf("%d", x & 0x20 ? 1 : 0);
printf("%d", x & 0x10 ? 1 : 0); 
printf("%d", x & 0x08 ? 1 : 0);
printf("%d", x & 0x04 ? 1 : 0); 
printf("%d", x & 0x02 ? 1 : 0); 
printf("%d", x & 0x01 ? 1 : 0);
```

Or use a loop and a _alking-one mask:

```
unsigned mask = 0x20 ;
while( mask != 0 )
{
    printf("%d", x & mask ? 1 : 0);  
    mask >>= 1 ;   
}
```